# Can a Python program be run through Atom text-editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

So, right now I beginning to look into AI programming and for that I will need to work heavily with Python. Atom is my go-to editor for all of my web-development projects and I was wondering if I can use it to save and run python projects as well.

Comment: Atom is a text editor. A Python script is just a text file. Why would you think a text editor can't be used to edit a text file?

Comment: @pkpnd Atom isn't just a text editor, it's an IDE. So the question is about the more advanced stuff than simple editing.

Comment: Lol, sorry about the tag. I just joined SO like a week or two ago. As for Atom I have only ever used it for web related things and I wasn't sure how I could run something that doesn't work through a web-server. I'm a newbie to most coding topics, only 1.5 years in.

Answer (score 4):

Atom can run Python scripts with ease using the Hydrogen package. Hydrogen can run code interactively in Atom, inspect data and plot.

To install the Hydrogen package select *Packages* -> *Settings View* -> *Install Packages/Themes* -> search for Hydrogen -> click the *Install* button to install it -> restart Atom to enable the Hydrogen package.

[image]
<sup>**Hydrogen package being used**   (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Atom can also display the graphical output of Python code inline as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]
<sup>**Inline plot in Atom**</sup>

Comment: I'm up to date, but the Hydrogen package doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Hydrogen is a featured package in Atom text editor, and it appears at the top of the featured package list. I have added the instructions for installing Hydrogen to my answer. I updated the Hydrogen package in my Atom text editor ten minutes ago, so I know that Hydrogen is still available.

Comment: Ok, I found it now. In the process of installing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Atom suport many plugins, you can use that: https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!